# Software to make Photo Video maker with music?

Tags: music, photography, video-editing, presentation

Well, i want to make a video for my dad on his birthday.  I want to make a video and save it, which will play a background song and flash photos with transitions (ex fade, slide in). It should allow to me to add Text to any photo inside the video/movie. then i want to dd closing credits text. It should be saved in video format like .flv , wmv and i want to download it  and share with family and friends.

please recommend both free and paid tools?

Comment: Does the OS matter, as you've named none?

Answer (score 4):

You can do exactly this sort of thing with [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), (and much more of course), I recently used it to generate a slide show of shots for part of a video of a friends funeral to send to the other side of the world to his parents.  There are lots of examples of how to this online including the [wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images), (and on the stack exchange sites).

- Free
- Cross Platform
- Downside is no GUI but lots of documentation and examples

Typical command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i audio.m4a -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4
```

Should create a video of all the .png files in the current directory with audio.m2a as the backing track. *You will probably have to spend a little time looking at all the options and examples to get exactly what you need but it is worth the effort.*

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been using the [Nero](http://www.nero.com/enu/) line of products to produce an end of year slide show for the past 8 years.  The software is sold as a suite, or, as individual products. [Nero Video 2015](http://www.nero.com/enu/products/nero-video/whats-new.php) currently retails for $60 US and provides many of the features you are looking for including:

- Text captions
- Audio soundtrack
- Transitions
- Themes
- Burning to multiple formats

To name a few.  They offer a 15 day trial that has some limitations.  I would recommend you download the trial and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, **Windows Live Movie Maker** should suffice for a very simple video with music. It lets you make simple transitions, text, music, and export to WMV/share.